# Get Child of Child Pages in custom Menu

Tags: php, wp-query, menus, sub-menu

Got this bit of code which runs which gets the Page ID and displays all the children under it. Which is good.

Part two of this is getting it to pull in the child of children items.

So currently looks like this

```
Main Menu Item
     Child Item
     Child Item
     Child Item
```

But I need it to look like this

```
Main Menu Item
     Child Item
          Child Item
          Child Item
          Child Item
```

This is the code I am using

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => 92,
    );
    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you need to with the [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) function:

```
<?php
wp_list_pages(
    [
        'child_of'    => 92,
        'title_li'    => false,
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    ]
);
?>
```